# How to consolidate a dataframe with several key-value columns with means from tidyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this dataframe:

```
df1 = read.table(text =
"
C1  C2  C3  C4
2   x   3   x
2   y   2   y
3   y   2   x
",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Columns C1 and C3 contain keys. Columns C2 and C4 contain values. I would like to convert the above dataframe into a form, where there is one column for keys and one column for values. Something like this:

```
  key val
1   2   x
2   2   y
3   3   y
4   3   x
5   2   y
6   2   x
```

How do you do this using means from `tidyr` or `dplyr`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simpler solution exists, but here is one approach could be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df1) %>%
   mutate(identifier = key %in% c("C1", "C3") + 1) %>%
   group_by(identifier) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   select(-key) %>%
   spread(identifier, value) %>%
   select(-row) %>%
   rename_all(~c("value", "key"))


# value key  
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 x     2    
#2 y     2    
#3 y     3    
#4 x     3    
#5 y     2    
#6 x     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
   gather(key_temp, value, C2, C4) %>% 
   mutate(key = ifelse(key_temp == "C2", C1, C3)) %>% 
   select(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this comparatively easily with the dev version of `tidyr`.  After `rename`ing the ccolumns with 'key', 'val', use `pivot_longer` (from the dev version of `tidyr`) which can reshape multiple sets of columns to long format from wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr) #tidyr_0.8.3.9000 
df1 %>%
    rename_all(~ c('val_1', 'key_1', 'val_2', 'key_2')) %>%        
    mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-ind, names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep="_") %>%  
    select(key, val)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  key     val
#  <chr> <int>
#1 x         2
#2 x         3
#3 y         2
#4 y         2
#5 y         3
#6 x         2
```

---

Regarding the `rename`ing part, it can be automated

```
df1 %>%
   rename_if(is.numeric, ~ str_c('val_', seq_along(.))) %>% 
   rename_if(is.character, ~ str_c('key_', seq_along(.))) %>%
   mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(-ind, names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_sep="_") %>%  
   select(key, val)
```